Equivalent formulation of group axioms.
I am having problems with the following exercise:
Let $G$ be a nonempty set with the binary operation $\cdot : G \times G \to G$. Show that $(G,\cdot)$ is a group if and only if
(a) There exists an $e\in G$ such that $ex = xe = x$ for all $x \in G$ ,
(b) For all $a,b\in G$ there exists exactly one $x\in G$ such that $xa = b$ and exactly one $y\in G$ such that $ay = b$,
(c) For all $a,b \in G$ with $ab=e$ we have $(xb)(ay)= xy$ for all $x,y\in G$.
I am using the following definition of a group: Let $G$ be a nonempty set with the binary operation $\cdot : G \times G \to G$. Then $(G, \cdot)$ is a group iff
(1) $\forall a,b,c\in G: a(bc) = (ab)c$,
(2) $\exists e \in G : \forall a \in G: ae = ea = a$,
(3) $\forall a \in G : \exists a' \in G : aa' = e = a'a$.
I tried setting $b = e$ in the condition (b) and playing around with that in (c) to show that then $x=y$ (so the left inverse is the right inverse) but I keep on finding myself finding an argumentation that needs associativity, and when I try to prove associativity, I find myself needing to know that the left and right inverses are equal. I'm in a bit of a muddle, which one is it best to prove first (out of inverse or associativity), and do I really have to combine (b) and (c) or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance!

Well, how are you defining a group?

We can prove this under a weaker assumption. Let $\cdot$ be a binary operation on $G$ with a neutral element $e$  such that
(1) For every $b$ there is some $a$ with $ab=e$.
(2) For all $a,b,x,y$ with $ab = e$ we have $(xb)(ay)=xy$.
Lemma 1. If $ab=e$, then $ba=e$.
Proof.  Apply (2) to $x=y=e$, this shows $ba = (eb)(ae) = ee = e$. $\checkmark$
Lemma 2. If $xy=e$, then $x(yz)=z$.
Proof. By Lemma 1 we have $yx=e$, so that we may apply (2) and get $x(yz)=(ex)(yz) = ez = z$. $\checkmark$
Lemma 3. For all $x,y,z$ we have $(xy)z = x(yz)$.
Proof. By (1) there is some $a$ with $a y = e$. From (2) we get $(xy)(az) = xz$ for all $z$. Hence, $(xy)(a(yz))=x(yz)$ for all $z$. But $a(yz)=z$ by Lemma 2. Hence, $(xy)z = x(yz)$. $\checkmark$
Corollary. $(G,\cdot)$ is a group.

Thank you! All I needed was Lemma 1 (which is so obvious when you see it) and everything falls into place.
